# making javascript push menu scrollable (no scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a push menu (left to right) that slides out from the left of the page sliding the page to the right.  I'm trying to add a safeguard to it to where if the links exceed the page height, the menu is scrollable.  Right now, it doesn't work and links get hidden.  Can someone help me figure out how to make the menu scrollable.

I've tried adding `scroll-y: scroll` to a couple of the css elements but that didn't seem to make any difference.  I'd like for the scroll feature to work on phones as well with scrolling via touch.

And also, I'd like to see how to disable scroll on the "body" when the menu is open.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
 $nav_list = $('#nav_list');
 $nav_list.click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
  $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
 });
});
```

```css
.pushmenu {
  background: #444;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;

}

.pushmenu h3 {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
  height: 16px;
}

.links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 25%;
  width: 50%;

}

.links li { margin-top: 30px; }

.links li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px;
}

.links li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

.links li a:hover:after { width: 70%; }

.links li a:active { color: #dbdbdb; }

.pushmenu-left { left: -300px; }

.pushmenu-left.pushmenu-open { left: 0; }

.pushmenu-push {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

.pushmenu-push-toright { left: 300px; }



.pushmenu, .pushmenu-push {
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<body class="pushmenu-push">
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>
   
   
 <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>

 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I think your looking for css overflow.  Setting overflow:auto and make sure you have the element and all parent elements height set to 100% should work. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Answer (score 1):

There's a CSS property called overflow which controls the contents when it exceeds the available space. Setting it to auto automatically adds a scrollbar.

```
pushmenu {
  background: #444;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;

}
```

Comment: Is there a way where it doesn't add an extra scrollbar?  Maybe where it uss the main scrollbar on the right?  OR no scrollbar at all in the menu

Comment: Try setting the overflow property to `visible` instead of `auto` and let me know if it works.

Comment: negative.  It now doesn't scroll at all

Comment: found a solution by adding an inner div element to code.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a way to do what I wanted with no scrollbar by adding an inner container and using overflow's on both.

```
.pushmenu {
  background: #444;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pushmenu_inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .pushmenu {
      background: #444;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      position: fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .main {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .pushmenu h3 {
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: 400;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      margin: 0;
      background: #333;
      height: 16px;
    }
    
    .links {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 0 0 25%;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .links li {
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .links li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 14px;
    }
    
    .links li a:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 20px;
      bottom: -5px;
      width: 0;
      height: 4px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
      transition: width 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .links li a:hover:after {
      width: 70%;
    }
    
    .links li a:active {
      color: #dbdbdb;
    }
    
    .pushmenu-left {
      left: -150px;
    }
    
    .pushmenu-left.pushmenu-open {
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .pushmenu-push {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .pushmenu-push-toright {
      left: 300px;
    }
    
    .pushmenu,
    .pushmenu-push {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="pushmenu-push">
  <nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left main">
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>
      <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
      $nav_list = $('#nav_list');
      $nav_list.click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
        $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is basically the same code I came up with last night you just renamed it to main...

Comment: No Same Code Real  _ @KDJ